# Knockout.js - Creating a reusable cascading select

Tags: javascript, knockout.js

Is it possible to create a reusable cascading combo box from a dictionary object using KO ?

For example, this data

```
{'A' : { 'A1':11, 'A2':12} , 
 'B' : { 'B1':21, 'B2':22, 'B3':33}, 
 'C' : { 'C1':31}}
```

would produce two cascading boxes, the first with the options 'A,B,C'. the second would update according to the selection. The dict might change in height but the tree will always be balanced.

Is it possible to create the elements from within a custom binding ? can a custom binding contain other custom bindings and subscribe to them ? is custom binding even the right approach here ?

I would appreciate some guidance.

Comment: looks like you might be looking for something like this http://knockoutjs.com/examples/cartEditor.html

Comment: Yes it is but the in this example the levels are known. I'm talking about dynamically creating the select boxes.

Comment: could you explain bit more in terms of what should happen on what action?

Comment: is it like if you select A, then show two sub selects. If you select B then show 3 sub selects and so on?

Comment: Sure. looking at the dict above two select boxes would be created - one for each level in the dict. The first one will contain A,B,C and the second empty. when the user selects 'A' the values in the second select would be A1,A2. if he select 'C' the values would be 'C1'. The thing is i might be getting a three or four level dict and so i dont know how many select boxes i need. I hope you understand my goal here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Basically this is what I have done

1. Create a predefined structure /class which knows if it has list of
   values or just a single value.
2. On the view side show the dropdown if its list else just show the text.
3. On the root vm nest the structure created in step one and create the dict.

Here is the VM

```
var optionVM = function (name,isList, v) {
    var self = this;
    self.name=ko.observable(name);
    if (isList) self.values = ko.observableArray(v);
    else self.value = ko.observable(v);
    self.isList = ko.observable(isList);
    self.selected = ko.observable();
}
var vm = function () {
    var self = this;
    var a1Vm = new optionVM('A1',true, [new optionVM('A11',false,111), new optionVM('A12',false,122)]);
    var aVm = new optionVM('A',true, [new optionVM('A2',false,'21'), a1Vm]);

    var d = new optionVM('Root',true, [aVm, new optionVM('B',false,'B1'),new optionVM('C',false,'C1')]);
    self.dict = ko.observable(d);

}

ko.applyBindings(new vm());
```

Here is the view

```
    <select data-bind='options:dict().values,optionsText:"name",value:dict().selected'>
</select>

<div data-bind="template: {name: 'template-detail', data: dict().selected}"></div>

<script type="text/html" id='template-detail'>
    <!-- ko if:$data.isList -->
    <span> List:</span>
    <select data-bind='options:values,optionsText:"name",value:selected'>
    </select>
        <div data-bind="template: {name: 'template-detail', data: selected}"></div>
    <!-- /ko -->
     <!-- ko ifnot:$data.isList -->
    Value:<span data-bind="text:value"></span>
     <!-- /ko -->

</script>
```

And here is the [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhanasekaran/27cSM/)

Improvements:

- You can use isArray to identify if its list in the optionVM.
- Some of the observables can be replaced with simple values if they are not going to change (e.g:name)

Comment: Hey @Dhana Krishnasamy - This is amazing ! I changed a few things [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/27cSM/1/). removed some unnecessary observables and added a build from js object. Thanks !

Comment: what is the best way to fetch the final value in `vm`? this is the output of the controller and I need to use it in my view model.

Comment: what do you mean by final value in vm? usually ko.mapping plugin is used to convert the plain js to observable.

Comment: if i choose "A" and then "A1" i need the value 11. Exactly what you display on the screen. You can bind it because it's the bottom of the recursion but how can i get back in the view model (without accessing the DOM) ?

Comment: in my example if you call dict().selected() you will get the user selected value, from there you can navigate up to the last value selected. use 'isList' to control the traversal and 'value' will have 11 for example